# Flexbox on iOS 8 - boxes collapse

Tags: ios, css, media-queries, flexbox

Using mediaqueries, on an iPad, landscape looks good with `flex-direction: row`. As soon as I turn to portrait (`flex-direction: column`) everything goes weird and collapses.

I use Codekit to compile my SCSS, with Autoprefixer running.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#">Project A</a></h3>
    <a href="#" class="project-thumb">
      <img src="/forrest.jpg">
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…</p>
    <p><a class="read-more" href="#">Read More</a></p>
  </li>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS:**

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 100%;

    @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
      flex: 0 0 49%;
    }
    > a {
      margin-top: auto;
    }
    h3 {…}
    h3 a {…}
    p {…}
  }
  .read-more {
    margin-top: auto;
    align-self: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

You can have a look at it here:

Codepen: http://codepen.io/achoukah/pen/pgEVmq

On my site: http://anwarchoukah.com/projects

Comment: Not really an answer to my own question, but by setting ```flex-direction: row``` everywhere, the collapse is avoided, but that will only appear as a column if its children are set to `flex: 0 0 100%`. So: the problem seems to be an issue with ```flex-direction: column```

Comment: Link to 'fix': http://codepen.io/achoukah/pen/WrGJdM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `flex-direction: column` on your `<ul>` (you also don't need to set it to `flex-direction: row` as that is the default).

Leave `flex-wrap: wrap` set on the `<ul>` - this is important.

You don't need `flex: 0 0 100%` on the `<li>`'s either.

Codepen Fork: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqOXWP